# iOS Device app like Animation

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, ios-simulator, cabasicanimation

Can anyone please guide me how can i achieve ios app animation ?

What kind of view controller, objects and implementation required ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shoud have:

- a root UIScrollView
- a programmatically-created UIView for every icon
- to iterate through the icons use [root subviews]
- an animation function shakeView:(UIView *)paramView that adds the delete icon and starts shaking the icon
- a global bool isShaking to have the state of the screen

Use touchesBegan to detect the view that is clicked/selected and the type of touch

That about sums it up. Try to create a maximum amount of elements programmatically.

Comment: Are you sure each icon should be its own UIView? It would be more lightweight to have a CALayer for each icon and then assign the `CGImageRef` of the icon to each layer. But as usual, one has to profile it, if it is worth the optimization.

Comment: It's the structure I used and it works flowlessly on iPhone 3G and higher.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I asked because on the mac a `NSView` is quite a hefty class which could lead to performance degradation. In UIKit `UIView` is obviously much more resource friendly.

Answer (score 2):

There is no harm if you take a look at this:

[Move UIViews to avoid collision like rearranging icons on Springboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535057/move-uiviews-to-avoid-collision-like-rearranging-icons-on-springboard)

check **Kristopher Johnson** Answer.

Comment: @Tariq- iPHONE Programmer: I am glad that i could "partially" help, i will keeping looking though because it will benefit everyone in this community = )

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Apple doesn't provide a GridView Class, but you can use the very handy TTLauncherView from Three20 that implements all the default behaviour for you:

https://github.com/facebook/three20

From their website http://three20.info/

> Three20 is a open source Objective-C library used by dozens of well-known brands in the App Store, including Facebook, Posterous, Pulse, Meetup.com, and SCVNGR. Three20 provides powerful view controllers such as the Launcher, the popular Photo Browser, and internet-aware tables.