# Effect like deletion in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I need hint/code like deletion/move app effect on iOS, normally i have started the code, I am using `UIButton` list in `UIScroll`.

So my question is that supposes I have 8 to 10 button in screen and i want to change their position with dragging. for example choose 6th button and move or set to between 1 and 2. when I put them in to between the position of other button will change.

I am using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for dragging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

download, [Tiles-v1.0.zip](http://undefinedvalue.com/sites/undefinedvalue.com/files/Tiles-v1.0.zip), and check code, this is what i used when i needed to implement that.

reference: [Move UIViews to avoid collision like rearranging icons on Springboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535057/move-uiviews-to-avoid-collision-like-rearranging-icons-on-springboard)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the code for dragging, the rest is easy. Just use UIView Animation.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
...
[button setFrame:newFrame];
...
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Basically, just move your buttons to the their new positions in that beginAnimations - commitAnimations block.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the helping, this code is for only dragging- and i want to like changing position of button.