# drag and drop subviews in scroll views like icons in ios home screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am creating an application in which the number of albums comes in a grid like apps come in home screen.I have implemented this functionality.

My problem is I want to rearrange or drag and drop my albums from one position to another position in my scroll view just like apps icons are draggable and dropable in home screen of iphone and ipad.

I search on the net and found the suggestions to use Three20 but as I have created my grid also so I do not want to use three 20 for this because using this will affect my whole UI implementation.

Please anyone suggest me or provide some sample code on how to drag and drop sub views in scroll views like iphone have in home screen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check my answer here [Effect like deletion in ios][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702761/effect-like-deletion-in-ios/10702981#10702981

Comment: @waheeda thanks for your answer but you have created some tile and implemented the touch events for this and in my requirements there is a scroll view and inside that scroll views there are many sub views so I need something that supports scroll view.Have you nay idea for that.

Comment: I had the same scenario, I implemented this logic on my scrollView subclass, i can send you the classes if you want.

Comment: Yes please it would be a great help to me.

Comment: @waheeda if possible please send me as it is some urgent.

Comment: hey waheeda I have shared my email id with you,Please sent the code.

Comment: thanks for your help, I will try this and will get back to you on this.Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @waheeda can you post you comment as a answer so that I can upvote and accept it.

Comment: @Gypsa did you solve the issue ?? can you post the answer for that

Comment: @waheeda can you post the answer

Comment: Here is the code of draggable subviews within UIScrollView. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18682463/MoveGrid.zip

Comment: @edwin u can get the code from above mentioned link.. i have uploaded on dropbox.

Comment: @waheeda thank u it works nicely .if you post it as answer i can up vote it . Others will also get benefits

Comment: @edwin i posted it as an answer.. but it was converted to comment :(

Comment: hai i need the same functionalitie but when am opening the link and running the project its showing nothing, if is it possible  can you please post the code...

Comment: @guptha. You can see output by running it on iPad.